# AppMenu of Qt Creator in GNOME Flashback

Tags: 14.04, gnome-classic, appmenu, qt-creator

I use *GNOME Flashback (Metacity)* in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installation because of performance (it's running in VirtualBox). In this mode, the menu bar of an application is usually placed below its title bar. Recently I downloaded Qt Creator (version 3.0.1-0ubuntu4) and it shows no menu bar in my GUI.

When I switch to Unity (called *Ubuntu (default)* in the chooser), the Qt Creator's menu is displayed correctly when I hover the mouse cursor over the top bar.

Is there any way to show AppMenu in *GNOME Flashback*? What should I do to use Qt Creator correctly with *GNOME Flashback*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the Qt Creator 3.0.1 package. I upgraded it to 3.1.1 (using the package repository of Utopic, following https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto#Recommended_alternative_to_pinning) and the menu is showing correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

This is known problem in GNOME Flashback. From terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides
'{"Gtk/ShellShowsAppMenu":<0>}'
```